# Tomcat webapp reverse proxy using RewriteRule

Tags: java, tomcat, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a simple webapp in tomcat, I want to route specific endpoint to external url (with the path after the endpoint), for example:

```
localhost/myapp/api/hello -> http://my-api-domain.com/hello
```

I added to the context.xml inside the META-INF folder of the app
Then added rewrite.config file to the WEB-INF folder with the following syntax:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/.*$ http://my-api-domain.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/.*$ hello.html [L]
```

It correctly routes all endpoints to hello.html, but when I navigate to /api/ it return the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
    java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:538)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.Substitution$RewriteRuleBackReferenceElement.evaluate(Substitution.java:43)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.Substitution.evaluate(Substitution.java:267)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteRule.evaluate(RewriteRule.java:135)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:351)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And without the '$1' in the rewrite config, a.g

```
RewriteRule ^/api/.*$ http://my-api-domain.com/ [L]
```

It returns 404:

```
/myapphttp://my-api-domain.com/
```

How can exit the app context and forward requests to external urls? And how do I make it transparent? (so it will seem that api requests are coming from myapp as well)

I tried adding P flag instead of L in the Rewrite, but it fails with the following:

```
Invalid flag in: RewriteRule ^/api/.*$ http://my-api-domain.com/ [P] flag: P
```

Tomcat version: 8.5.12
, Java version: 1.8.0_144

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a webapp that answers the requirements (reverse proxy, allows configuration).

[j2ep](http://j2ep.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Tomcat's rewrite valve does not support any form of reverse proxy. Neither does any other out of the box component.